# Comparing hash made with random salt PHP, Java

Tags: java, php, hash

I’ve got a problem with hash comparing. I’m developing app that needs to authenticate user. In most cases that’s not a problem but the app is a supplement to existing website, so that website has its own authentication method. The website was made using Contao Framework and it is hard for me to find useful information.

After search i’ve found that website is using Encryption::hash() method which in most cases uses code below:

```
crypt($strPassword, '$6$' . md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . '$’);
```

As anybody can see the salt is random so I can’t recreate hash.

I’ve got string with user password that he typed, code above and hash made by code above from database.
Is there anyway (I’m sure there is because website is working) to check if string with user password is correct?
Or in other words, if hash from database was made using password that user typed to login.

I would like to have solution in Java but PhP would be also accepted.

Please help.

Comment: You should still be able to check the hash using the same code shown in Example #1 here: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Comment: @Bailey Herbert Thanks that works! Where can I add you some reputation points? Can you move this comment to an answer? I will accept this solution.

Answer (score 0):

A random salt can't be recreated. You could do the following:
1/ save the random salts in the database as a second password.
You would then have in the database:

```
username  | password   | salt
sridesmet | md5string  | randomgeneratedsalt
```

If you want to check if the password that the user used is correct, you just do:

```
(md5($UserTypedPassword.$saltDB) == $passwordDB)
```

2/ don't use a random salt, use a normal salt, like $username.'Hellothisisasalt'
The method would be thesame as above, except that the salt doesn't have to be stored.

As for Contao CMS, I think they use the following methods: http://api.contao.org/classes/Contao.Encryption.html

Edit:
It's even the Contao authors's idea to store the hash in the database: https://github.com/contao/core/issues/142

The login with Contao works like this:

```
    $blnAuthenticated = ($strSalt == '') ? ($strPassword === sha1(\Input::postRaw('password'))) : ($strPassword === sha1($strSalt . \Input::postRaw('password')));
```

Source: https://github.com/contao/core/blob/master/system/modules/core/library/Contao/User.php